# Locally pushing GitHub Repository to master branch:Not pushing folders

Tags: git, github

So I've got a local copy of my github repository and just pushed some local changed to the master branch.

Only individual files were added and not new folders containing files

Any idea why the folders weren't uploaded?

---

I only used
git clone

git add .

git commit -m "blah"

git push origin master

to make changes to my pre-existing repository
I did not make a whole new repository with git init
and didn't do anything with "bare" or whatever that command is.

Comment: It sounds like the files within the folders you are expecting to be pushed might be being filtered by something within the .gitignore file of the repository?

Comment: What is your current path? Git add . only affects that. Use git add /. or git add -A on git 2.0 to  add all files and subfolders in your working tree.

Comment: Are you sure that you are in the right directory? If you want to add everything in the repo with `git add .`, you must be at the top level of the repo. Otherwise, `git add -A` is a better option for adding everything.

Comment: @Benjamin That was it.
Had the folder name I was trying to upload in my gitignore.
*facepalm*

Kinda new here so I'm assuming the only way I can give you credit is if you re-submit your suggestion as an official answer?

Comment: Upvoting also adds a smaller credit, but you might not be able to do this at your rep level. Adding as an answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As determined in the comments to the question -

If you have some files, or any parent folder to those files matching a pattern in the project's `.gitignore` file, without specific exceptions for the files you are trying to add

```
git add .
```

Then *git will not stage those files*, therefore they will not be committed or pushed by subsequent commands.